# Robots.txt not working because my site is still searchable

Tags: php, html, robots.txt

I put a robots.txt in my server

 This is the code that I putted in

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

I just want my entire site won't be searchable in google.

 I also put in the `NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW` on the header of my site, Here's the code:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

I'm wondering why is it that when I try to search the my website in google it is still showing up. what has happened here? 
Should this take effect immedietly? or what?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated as well as rewarded! Thanks! :)

Comment: It's possible that search engines have yet to revisit your site since you added the robots.txt file. They won't be aware of the new instructions until they come back to check on your site.

Comment: propagation sir. It doesn't happen immediately.

Comment: How would I let search engine visit my site? or how would they revisit it again?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

It never takes effect immediately. Google has to go to your site and look at the updated robots.txt file, which can take hours or days.

I suggest you make an account on [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). 
This will give you insight into what Google knows about your site.

I believe other large search engines offer similar functionality. It's worth looking at sometime.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if you google your domain it will show up (I had this myself with a robots.txt-disabled website myself). However, the content will not be indexed.

If your website has already been in Google's SERPs, it will take a while (probably a few weeks to a couple of months) until your content disapears.